# Need to Batch a Large DataTable and write each batch to a Text file - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, batch-processing

I have a requirement that I need to query a DB and fetch the records in a Data Table. The Data Table has 20,000 records. 
I need to batch these records in Batches of 100 records each and write these batches into a individual Text files.

Till now I have been able to batch the records in batches of 100 each using IEnumerable(of DataRow).

I am now facing issue in writing the IEnumeable(Of DatRow) to a Text File.

My code is a below:

```
Dim strsql = "Select * from myTable;"
Dim dt as DataTable
Using cnn as new SqlConnection(connectionString)
cnn.Open()
Using dad as new SqlAdapter(strsql ,cnn)
dad.fill(dt)
End Using
cnn.Close()
End Using 

Dim Chunk = getChunks(dt,100)
For each chunk as IEnumerable(Of DataRow) In Chunks
Dim path as String = "myFilePath"
If Not File.Exists(myFilePath) Then
  //** Here I will write my Batch into the File.
End If
Next

Public Iterator Function getChunks(byVal Tab as DataTable, byVal size as Integer) as IEnumerable (Of IEnumerable(of DataRow))

Dim chunk as List(Of DataRow) = New List(of DataRow)(size)
For Each row As DataRow in tab.Rows
chunk.Add(row)
if chunk.Count = size Then
Yield chunk
chunk = New List(of DataRow0(size)
Next
if chunk.Any() Then Yield chunk

End Function
```

Need your help to write the IEneumerable of DataRows into a Text file for each Batch of Records.

Thanks

:)

Comment: You already know what to do because you're doing it here: `For Each row As DataRow in tab.Rows`. That's how you enumerate a list of `DataRows`, regardless of the type of list. Just substitute your list, i.e. `chunk`, for `tab.Rows`.

Comment: Why the C# tag? Also you shouldn't use tags (VB.Net) in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code is needlessly complex. If this is all you're doing, then using a datatable is unnecessary/unwise; this is one of the few occasions I would advocate using a lower level datareader to keep the memory impact low

Writing a db table to a file, quick, easy and low memory consumption:

```
Dim dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

Dim sb as New StringBuilder
Dim lineNum = -1
Dim batchSize = 100

While dr.Read()

  'turn the row into a string for our file
  For x = 0 to dr.FieldCount -1
    sb.Append(dr.GetString(x)).Append(",")
  Next x
  sb.Length -= 1 'remove trailing comma
  sb.AppendLine()

  'keep track of lines written so we can batch accordingly 
  lineNum += 1
  Dim fileNum = lineNum \ batchSize
  File.AppendAllText($"c:\temp\file{fileNum}.csv", sb.ToString())

  'clear the stringbuilder 
  sb.Length = 0

End While
```

If you really want to use a datatable, there isn't anything stopping you swapping this `while dr` For a `For Each r as DataRow in myDatatable.Rows`

Please note, this isn't an exercise in creating a fully escaped csv, nor formatting the data; it is demonstrating the concept of having a firehose of data and simply writing it to N different files by utilising the fact that doing an integer divide on every number from 0 to 99 will result in 0 (and hence go in file 0) and then very number from 1 to 199 will result in 1 (and hence lines go in file 1) etc, and doing this process on a single stream of data, or single iteration of N items

You could build the file lines in the string builder and write them every batchSize `if lineNum Mod batchSize = batchSize - 1`, if you feel that it would be more efficient than calling file appendalltext (which opens and closes the file)

Comment: Yes, I can see if the DataTable won't fit in memory but this is an long time to keep a connection open.

Comment: What is your definition of "long time"?

Comment: For loops, writing to files?

Comment: Consider that disks are typically faster than networks; it think it's reasonable to assert that transferring a table contents across a network will be the slowest step here and hence the connection will be open for the same time regardless of whether its data stream is written to memory or disk. I think it also reasonable to assert that 20,000 items would take a couple of seconds or less, for a simple `select *`, and I'm certain you've written many (complex) queries in your career that take longer to run than this.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this with a table of a little over 1,500 records and 10 fields. The file creation took a little over 5 seconds (excluding data access). All things being equal (which I know they are not) that would be over 13 seconds writing the files.

Since your problem was with the iterator I assume the there were no memory issues with the `DataTable`.

You can include more than one database object in a `Using` block by using a comma to designate a list of objects in the `Using`.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim myFilePath = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TestLoop\DataFile"

    Dim strsql = "Select * from myTable;"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(strsql, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    sw.Start()
    Dim StartRow = 0
    Dim EndRow = 99
    Dim FileNum = 1
    Dim TopIndex = dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Do
        For i = StartRow To EndRow
            Dim s = String.Join("|", dt.Rows(i).ItemArray)
            File.AppendAllText(myFilePath & FileNum & ".txt", s & Environment.NewLine)
        Next
        FileNum += 1
        StartRow += 100
        EndRow += 100
        If EndRow >= TopIndex Then
            EndRow = TopIndex
        End If
    Loop Until StartRow >= TopIndex
    sw.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought your code was a great use of the iteration function.

Here is the code for your iterator.

```
Public Iterator Function getChunks(ByVal Tab As DataTable, ByVal size As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of DataRow))
    Dim chunk As List(Of DataRow) = New List(Of DataRow)(size)
    For Each row As DataRow In Tab.Rows
        chunk.Add(row)
        If chunk.Count = size Then
            Yield chunk
            chunk = New List(Of DataRow)(size)
        End If
    Next
    If chunk.Any() Then Yield chunk
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = LoadDataTable()
    Dim myFilePath As String = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TestLoop\DataFile"
    Dim FileNum = 1
    For Each chunk As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) In getChunks(dt, 100)
        For Each row As DataRow In chunk
            Dim s = String.Join("|", row.ItemArray)
            File.AppendAllText(myFilePath & FileNum & ".txt", s & Environment.NewLine)
        Next
        FileNum += 1
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub
```

You just needed to nest the For Each to get at the data rows.